# What is "group" from Gemfiles in the ruby language?

Tags: ruby, gemfile

I'm just learning Ruby/Rails. Consider this excerpt from a Gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

What is `group` in the ruby language? I initially thought of a function but why would the thing that the function returns be followed by a `do` - `end` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* just a plain old function, it's not part of the language. See http://bundler.io/groups.html

Functions can accept blocks (the `do/end` part). The function's return value isn't "followed" by `do/end`, the `do/end` is one of the arguments to the function, along with the symbol `:production`.

Similarly, `gem` is also just a function, not a part of Ruby.

Comment: Interesting. TBH I only skimmed the site you referenced and could not find information saying it's not part of ruby. However given your reputation I'm blindly accepting this answer.

Comment: You don't have to believe me. Just try running `irb` and type `group`.

Comment: Okay I did this. Now I realized I might have mixed something up. When you say "just a function, not part of Ruby" you mean it is no native ruby function but it is a function declared in the ruby language right? (Initially I thought you meant no ruby is involved at all)

Comment: It's not a built-in function, but it is part of a library (Ruby Gems) which has been included with Ruby since version 1.9. It is not a "native" function, it is implemented in plain old Ruby. [Here, to be specific](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/681e214a30509029f11e329710a2b10b024b61a5/lib/rubygems/request_set/gem_dependency_api.rb).

Comment: Actually, it's not a function at all, it's a method.

Comment: @JörgWMittag For simplicity's sake, I didn't feel the need to bring this up, but yes.